# Facebook friend picker not picking friends in SDK 3.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I am creating an app which wants to list the facebook friends. For that i did the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{        
    arrayFriends=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
        [FBSession.activeSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
            switch (state) {
                case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                {
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                        message:error.localizedDescription
                                                                       delegate:nil
                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alertView show];
                }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }];
    }       
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
        // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
        self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
        self.friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
        self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
    }

    [self.friendPickerController loadData];
    [self.friendPickerController clearSelection];
    [self.friendPickerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 77, 320, 383)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.friendPickerController.view];
    // iOS 5.0+ apps should use [UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: viewcontroller with list of friends]
 you can get friend list like this image for that you need to add below code in your viewWillAppear:method

```
 if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
    // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
    self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
    self.friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
    self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
}

[self.friendPickerController loadData];
[self.friendPickerController clearSelection];

[self presentModalViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES];
```

for done and cancel button actions we should call below methods respectively,

```
- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender{
  //code goes here
}
- (void)facebookViewControllerCancelWasPressed:(id)sender{
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Can i able to change the background color of this ViewController ? I tried the following code but the background didn't changed.... [self.friendPickerController.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.friendPickerController.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
        [self.friendPickerController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: @murali Can i fetch username of the selected friends?

Comment: this modal view is presented but the table view is still not getting populated with the contact list. any suggestions how to fix this??

Answer (score -1):

A couple of things you need to consider that are not explained in the tutorial that iSpark is using as source material (and which one of their 2013 commenters probably wish they knew about):

1. The users appearing in the friend picker are only users that have installed the app themselves. This is newer, probably not applicable at the time of the original post.
2. You need the user_friends permission from the user to see any friends.

Some more here: [Facebook iOS Select Friends Table Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314154/facebook-ios-select-friends-table-blank)