# Facebook iOS Select Friends Table Blank

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to add the "select friends" to my iOS app. I set up the login view. Once I login I open the friend picker but it comes up blank. I see the table with the done and cancel buttons but there are no friends loaded into the table.

```
- (IBAction)selectFriendsButtonAction:(id)sender {
    if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
        // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
        self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
        self.friendPickerController.title = @"Select Friends";
        self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
    }
    [self.friendPickerController loadData];
    [self.friendPickerController clearSelection];
    [self presentViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior to opening the friend picker controller ensure your Facebook session is active by calling this:

```
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
    [FBSession.activeSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
        // Handle error
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two things you need to take care of that you may well not realize you need even if you understand the rest of the Facebook SDK pretty well.

1. The dialog will only show friends that have also installed the app.
2. You have to ask for the user_friends permission during your login flow.

For 1., create or use a test user you already have and run your app with that user in order to authorize the app for basic access ("install" it).

For 2, add that permission to your login flow, log out and back in with the sender you're testing (probably your own user), and if you don't get prompted to grant it even then, uninstall the app via https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications.

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-get-facebook-friends-in-swift/ discusses some of this. The Facebook docs themselves either don't mention the 2 issues at all or it's buried.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "FBFriendPickerViewController", it seems return friends who also use this APP. In Facebook document: after API Graph v2.0, "me/friends" will only return friends that also use the app. I think that's why the friend table is blank.

There is another option that you can use "FBTaggableFriendPickerViewController" instead. But your APP will need to be reviewed by Facebook before it can get data back. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/taggable_friends?locale=zh_TW)