# FBFriendPickerViewController showing and empty table on iOS. Place Picker running fine

Tags: ios, facebook

I have this code, copied from FB samples (where it runs fine), but in my App is showing just a blank table for the Friend Picker. Place Picker is running fine showing a full table.

What´s wrong with Friend Picker?

In the AppDelegate:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FBFriendPickerViewController class];
    [FBPlacePickerViewController class];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

In the View Controller:

```
- (IBAction)pickFriendsButtonClick:(id)sender {
// FBSample logic
// if the session is open, then load the data for our view controller
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"user_friends"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                      FBSessionState state,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                                      if (error) {
                                          UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                              message:error.localizedDescription
                                                                                             delegate:nil
                                                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                          [alertView show];
                                      } else if (session.isOpen) {
                                          [self pickFriendsButtonClick:sender];
                                      }
                                  }];
    return;
}
// Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
friendPickerController.delegate = self;

[friendPickerController loadData];

[friendPickerController presentModallyFromViewController:self animated:YES handler:nil];
}
- (IBAction)pickPlacesButtonClick:(id)sender{
    // FBSample logic
    // if the session is open, then load the data for our view controller
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"user_friends"]
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                          FBSessionState state,
                                                          NSError *error) {
                                          if (error) {
                                              UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                              [alertView show];
                                          } else if (session.isOpen) {
                                              [self pickPlacesButtonClick:sender];
                                          }
                                      }];
        return;
    }
    // Initialize the place picker
    FBPlacePickerViewController *placePickerController = [[FBPlacePickerViewController alloc] init];
    // Set the place picker title
    placePickerController.title = @"Pick Place";
    // Hard code current location to Menlo Park, CA
    placePickerController.locationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.453827, -122.182187);
    // Configure the additional search parameters
    placePickerController.radiusInMeters = 1000;
    placePickerController.resultsLimit = 50;
    placePickerController.searchText = @"restaurant";
    placePickerController.delegate = self;

    // Load the place data
    [placePickerController loadData];
    // Show the place picker modally
    [placePickerController presentModallyFromViewController:self animated:YES handler:nil];
}

- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Done pressed");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)facebookViewControllerCancelWasPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Cancel pressed");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Project:

1. Made a brand new Project with just a Single View.
2. Added 2 buttons and connected them with the action.
3. Copy/Paste the code from the sample.
4. Add the Facebook Framework.
5. Edit the plist file to add the Facebook Application numbers.

My table (Place Picker) is full for restaurants.
My table (Friend Picker) is still empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**step 1: open Facebook session if not exist**

```
if ( !FBSession.activeSession.isOpen ) {
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends" ]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                      [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                  }];
}
```

**step 2: request to get friends list (include require fields)**

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=picture,name,username,location,first_name,last_name" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
         [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary* result, NSError *error) {
         //store result into facebookFriendsArray 
         self.facebookFriendsArray = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
         }];
```

**step 3: reload data to tableView from facebookFriendsArray**

Comment: can you update your answer on how to make  FBFriendPickerViewController loads data from self.facebookFriendsArray. Thanks!

Comment: self.facebookFriendsArray is NSArray loaded from FBRequest (check above answer) and thereafter use standard method to load NSArray into UITableView.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I can't make it work, can you update your response on how to load self.facebookFriendsArray into  FBFriendPickerViewController? Specially with the example that user3614102 used.

Comment: openActiveSessionWithPermissions has been deprecated by Facebook. Instead, you can use [FBSession.activeSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error){}];

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you need to consider that are not explained well by Facebook in the current docs.

1. The users appearing in the friend picker are only users that have installed the app themselves. This is newer, probably not applicable at the time of the original post.
2. You need the user_friends permission from the user to see any friends.

Some more here: [Facebook iOS Select Friends Table Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314154/facebook-ios-select-friends-table-blank)

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest Facebook API (v 2.0) you can not pick friends list directly. By default you can access only three permissions that are email, public_profile and user_friends.

For any additional permission you are required to ask Facebook (you can do it from Facebook developer account where you have created app) and also read change log because again apps created on or after 30 April, 2014 can not access old APIs.

if you have app created before stated date then use old Facebook API (I would recommend 3.13.1) and deprecated function (**openActiveSessionWithPermissions**) to create FBSession.

I had same issue and took me long to figure out. let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: If I use the XCode demo project included on Facebook SDK, it works fine, I can see all my friends on a table. But if I copy/paste the FriendPicker (from the demo project) in my own project I just get a blank table. In both projects I have granted the right permissions. I'm using openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions @user_friends. It was like this before april 30 and still is like that.

Comment: follow steps as stated in my answer

Comment: use openActiveSessionWithPermissions. if you will use openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions and @user_friends you will only able to fetch friends those have your app installed. (now in your case it might be possible that none of your Facebook friends have authorized app which is why tableView is empty.

Comment: @iamvin, openActiveSessionWithPermissions is deprecated on the latest SDK version (3.17 at the time of this writing)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the permissions array you are using on **user sign up** includes the `user_friends` permission. If you're copying code it's easy to miss.

   ```
   NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"public_profile", @"user_friends"];
   ```
2. Reference the array on Sign Up:

   ```
   [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

   ...

   ];
   ```

Then do the following in FB developer dashboard:

3. Create at least 2 test users
4. Set them to friends with each other

And on your app:

5. Have each user log in and provide permissions for your app (FB will only show users who are friends AND using the app)

**The second user should be able to see the first user in their friend list.**